# Incrementar dias a una fecha dada con arreglo anidado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy principiante en Python y estoy intentando realizar un programa que lea una fecha (`AAAA-MM-DD`) dada por el usuario y me permita mostrar 5 días subsecuentes a la fecha dada y realizar los cambios de día, mes o año en su caso ¿Alguna idea? Me quede atorada ahí.

Este es mi código, no sé si es lo mas óptimo, pero es una parte de lo que quiero hacer:

```
fecha=input("Introduce una fecha:")

fecha2=fecha.split("-")

anio=int(fecha2[0])

mes=int(fecha2[1])

dia=int(fecha2[2])

if mes==1 or mes==3 or mes==5 or mes==7 or mes==8 or mes==10 or mes==12:
    diasmes=31
elif mes==2:
    if (anio % 4 == 0 and anio % 100 != 0 or anio % 400 == 0):
        diasmes=29
    else:
        diasmes=28  
elif mes==4 or mes==6 or mes==9 or mes==11:
    diasmes=30
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay múltiples formas de abordar el problema como casi siempre, partiendo de lo que ya tienes yo consideraría primero validar la fecha, si la fecha introducida no es válida no tiene sentido el resto. Hecho esto podemos plantear el un algoritmo muy simple teniendo en cuenta que solo vamos a sumar como máximo 5 días (por lo que solo vamos a movernos entre dos meses a lo sumo):

- Si el día del mes más el número de días incrementados es menor del número máximo de días simplemente sumamos los días.
- Si lo anterior no se cumple deberemos sumar uno al mes con la salvedad de que si estamos en Diciembre el mes pasará a ser Enero y sumamos uno al año.
  El día de la nueva fecha será los días que superan al máximo de días del mes.

El código podría quedar algo así, si no he metido la pata en alguna parte:

```
def cinco_dias(fecha):
    año, mes, dia = (int(n) for n in fecha.split("-"))

    if año < 1 or not isinstance(año, int):
        raise ValueError("El año debe ser un entero mayor de 0")

    if mes in (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12):
        dias_mes = 31

    elif mes == 2:
        if año % 4 == 0 and (año % 100 != 0 or año % 400 == 0):
            dias_mes = 29
        else:
            dias_mes = 28

    elif mes in (4, 6, 9, 11):
        dias_mes = 30

    else:
        raise ValueError("El mes debe ser un entero entre 1 y 12 incluidos")

    if not 1 <= dia <= dias_mes:
        raise ValueError("{} no es un día válido para el {:04d}/{:02d}".format(dia, año, mes))

    dias = []
    for n in range(1, 6):
        if dia + n <= dias_mes:
            dias.append('{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(año, mes, dia + n))
        else:
            if mes != 12:
                dias.append('{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(año, mes+1, n - (dias_mes - dia)))
            else:
                dias.append('{:04d}-01-{:02d}'.format(año + 1, n - (dias_mes - dia)))

    return dias

fecha = input("Introduce una fecha: ")
print(cinco_dias(fecha))
```

Ejemplos de salidas:

```
Introduce una fecha: 2020-02-27
['2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-01', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03']

Introduce una fecha: 2018-12-29
['2018-12-30', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03']

Introduce una fecha: 2023-02-29
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(cinco_dias(fecha))
  File "prueba.py", line 23, in cinco_dias
    raise ValueError("{} no es un día válido para el {}/{}".format(dia, mes, año))
ValueError: 29 no es un día válido para el 2023/02

Introduce una fecha: 2018-04-31
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(cinco_dias(fecha))
  File "prueba.py", line 23, in cinco_dias
    raise ValueError("{} no es un día válido para el {:04d}/{:02d}".format(dia, año, mes))
ValueError: 31 no es un día válido para el 2018/04
```

Cabe destacar que lo anterior no tiene mucho sentido, excepto en ámbito académico o lúdico, cuando Python ya provee de esta funcionalidad gracias al módulo `datetime` y al método `datetime.timedelta`:

```
import datetime

def añadir_dias(fecha, dias):
    fecha = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha, "%Y-%m-%d")
    fechas = [datetime.datetime.strftime(fecha + datetime.timedelta(days=d), "%Y-%m-%d")
                  for d in range(1, días + 1)]
    return fechas

fecha = input("Introduce una fecha: ")
print(añadir_dias(fecha), 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

A menos que tengas alguna restricción en cuanto al tipo de solución, creo que esto es lo más simple que puedes hacer:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

fecha_ingreso = input("Introduce una fecha:")
d,m,a = [int(v) for v in fecha_ingreso.split("-")]

fecha = date(a, m, d)
for i in range(1,6):
  newdate = fecha + timedelta(days=i)
  print(newdate.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```

- Nos apoyamos en el módulo base [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
- En primer lugar, no es necesario manejar una lista para los valores ingresados, haciendo: `d,m,a = [int(v) for v in fecha_ingreso.split("-")]`, separamos los valores ingresados, los convertimos a enteros y los asignamos a tres variables para cada parte de la fecha
- Creamos un objeto `date` mediante `date(a, m, d)` que representará la fecha ingresada
- Como pides mostrar las siguientes 5 fechas subsecuentes a la ingresada puedes hacer un ciclo usando `range(1,6)` que irá de 1 a 5.
- Dentro del ciclo usamos un objeto [`timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) que básicamente representa una duración, en este caso de días, y que nos sirve para hacer aritmética de fechas de forma simple, en este caso `newdate = fecha + timedelta(days=i)` lo cual irá incrementando de a un día la fecha ingresada.
- Por último, imprimimos la fecha por pantalla usando `strftime()` que nos permite darle un formato adecuado

Answer (score 0):

Existen funciones de manejo de fechas que te ayudan y permiten operar con fechas realizando ellas mismas la conversión que explicas. En tu caso sería:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
fecha='2017-12-29'

# Formateamos la fecha según el formato especificado en la cadena
# Si la fecha es día/mes/año, en vez de '%Y-%m-%d' debe ser '%d-%m-%Y'
fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

# Añadimos 5 días (con timedelta)
nueva_fecha = fecha + timedelta(days=5)

# Convertimos en string de nuevo
print(str(nueva_fecha))
```

Si fecha es igual a '2017-12-29' de devuelve '2018-01-03'.

Échale un vistazo a la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) de `datetime` y manejo de tiempos en Python para conocer mejor lo que estás haciendo. Entre otras cosas verás como formatear fechas introducidas en formato día/mes/año, pues el ejemplo que te muestro es en el formato año/mes/día.

Saludos :)

Comment: Gracias inf. muy util